# localStorage in Stack Snippets?

Tags: feature-request, stack-snippets

Can we have it? Please?

1. Not a security issue, it's another domain anyways and I doubt snippets will steal information from each other (+ [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) uses it flawlessly btw)
2. Can use it to demonstrate persistent data in form fields, such as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26009024)
3. Cooler games in codegolf, remember those games? Now there can be states.
4. Since document.cookie is off limits (not sure why either because cookie is on another domain too)

Comment: Problem: all Stack Snippets will share local storage. Also, [kind of a security issue.](http://feross.org/fill-disk/)

Comment: @doppelgreener I don't see how filldisk would work. It uses frames, and external sites. Current stack snippets doesn't even allow this. Also, all snippets sharing data, that would just mean if I declared a variable `mykey`, if by coincidence another user decided to use `mykey`, it would just clash, not a security issue.

Comment: I guess we just have to rely on stack snippets to be coded properly (for stack snippets itself) and clear stack snippets' local storage at the beginning.

Comment: @doppelgreener Sorry I still don't see why this is an issue. If you clear it at the beginning, then it defeats the purpose of having persistent data. Which also is not a security issue, because that persistent data cannot communicate with a remote server.

Comment: Consider my post to start with "I guess this isn't a problem then, we just have..." - does that clear that up? :) I'm suggesting if there isn't a security issue, this should be ok, we just have to rely on people to be smart and guard their snippets from other ones, the possibility of local storage already being full, etc. Maybe have stack snippets empty its own storage before and after each snippet run to enforce it being kept clean for each individual snippet?

Comment: @doppelgreener Right, but if the beginning of the code is `localStorage.clear();`, then it removes the current snippet's local storage as well. If you mean keep every snippet's local storage separate from other's, that'd be a very difficult task, because you'd need multiple domains which I doubt S.E would do. There's no reason to do so anyways, if clashing localstorage is found, it does little to no damage. Worst case: the snippet doesn't work because of a bad initial value, best case: it works as intended.

Comment: that's not my issue; I'll take this to an answer.

Comment: I'm getting tons of disagreement, but I feel I've given evidence to show that this will not be a security issue. Can a downvoter please explain why this would not be beneficial to implement into the current stack snippets?

Comment: two downvotes is not a ton of disagreement...cheer up...

Answer (score -1):

This seems okay. I have a concern though about part of this. I'll ignore whether there might be security issues with allowing local storage; if there are someone else can point them out.

### One concern: snippets will have to guard against a muddy environment

If snippets are going to be using local storage, they'll be sharing each others' local storage.

That has some implications for each script:

- There's no guarantee there will be enough local storage space left for any new data.
- If a script wants to load a value that hasn't been set yet, e.g. it expects you to run it, close it, and re-run it and persist a value between those two runs, there's no guarantee that the value the snippet loads will be the value it set, or that the value will make any sense. It might load `localstorage.foo` and find the `foo` a completely different script set.

This isn't a show-stopper, but it means scripts will have to do one or two things:

1. Clear local storage before the script runs, or delete stuff from it, so as to assure there's enough space for the script itself.
2. Make sure any value it loads makes sense, so that the script doesn't break on running from bad input.

Again, not a show-stopper. The problem I find with this is that #1, and *maybe* #2, might usually not exist in production code. It's boilerplate that a well-written script might include, which the reader might be expected to delete in their own usage of the code.

That makes the example a bit messy, and unreliable if it doesn't want to go to this trouble. Both of those outcomes would be bad.

### Let's enforce keeping local storage clean.

Do one of the following:

#### 1. Wipe the slate for every new snippet.

Before and after each stack snippet runs, have stack snippets clear local storage so as to guarantee each script starts with a clean slate, and to leave no excess data consumption on the user's machine.

#### 2. Wipe the slate periodically, but allowing for data persistence snippets.

Some snippets may rely on being able to persist data between individual runs of that snippet. Option #1 would break these.

So instead, clear the data periodically on some mechanism:

- Clear the data when a snippet from a different answer to the previous one is run. (This means snippets from the same answer can share local storage values with each other, but when you run a snippet from another answer, it gets cleared first.)
- Clear the data periodically, e.g. if it's been over half an hour since the last snippet was run. (This allows multiple answers to share snippet data, or the question and its answers, which could get messy in the bad way and necessitate protective code, or could be fine.)

Comment: This seems too complex. Just have localStorage recycle after half an hour. Just long enough to see what it can do. Generally, the OP will be running the code, and then refreshing it once or twice to see if it works or not. A person searching from google, etc. The only place where a lot of concurrent or a lot of snippets would be running would be codegolf.

Comment: @DaveChen `localstorage.clear();` - run snippet - `localstorage.clear();` -- doesn't seem more complex to me than a timer mechanism.

Comment: You cannot simply clear, because that will remove all previous data from the snippet as well. The purpose of the snippet is to work, before having the OP import it into his/her environment. Not the downvoter btw.

Comment: Yes, that's my point, you can clear, and too bad for that script, find some other way to demonstrate whatever they're trying to demonstrate (like have a "load some useful data" button)

Comment: If we want to have a timing mechanism, that could work better. I'm just befuddled by you saying a simplistic clear is *too complex*, and then suggesting something *more complex.*